# How to select language nodes from xml file using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

Here is my XML file:

```
<Touren xmlns="urn:schemas-TOURDATA:SchemaExtension">
  <Tour TourID="00" LastChange="00" LastChangeBy="00" Created="00" CreatedBy="00">    
    <OBJECT_TEXT_NAME xmlns="urn:schemas-TOURDATA:Tour">
      <string xmlns="urn:TOURDATA:i18n" xml:lang="de-DE">TEXT GERMAN</string>
      <string xmlns="urn:TOURDATA:i18n" xml:lang="en-GB">TEXT ENGLISH</string>
    </OBJECT_TEXT_NAME>
```

And here my XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:td1="urn:schemas-TOURDATA:SchemaExtension" 
xmlns:td2="urn:schemas-TOURDATA:Tour">

<xsl:template match="/td1:Touren">
<xsl:apply-templates select="td1:Tour">
</xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="td1:Tour">
<p><xsl:value-of select="td2:OBJECT_TEXT_BESCHREIBUNG">!!TEXT GERMAN HERE!!</xsl:value-of></p>
<p><xsl:value-of select="td2:OBJECT_TEXT_BESCHREIBUNG">!!TEXT ENGLISH HERE!!</xsl:value-of></p>    
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

How do I select the *de-DE* and *en-GB* `string` nodes in order to output them using `xsl:value-of`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You address the `string` element and apply a predicate filter specifying the value of the `@xml:lang` attribute:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:td1="urn:schemas-TOURDATA:SchemaExtension" 
    xmlns:td2="urn:schemas-TOURDATA:Tour"
    xmlns:td3="urn:TOURDATA:i18n">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/td1:Touren">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="td1:Tour">
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="td1:Tour">
        <p><xsl:value-of select="td2:OBJECT_TEXT_NAME/td3:string[@xml:lang='de-DE']"/></p>
        <p><xsl:value-of select="td2:OBJECT_TEXT_NAME/td3:string[@xml:lang='en-GB']"/></p>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks Mads. Perfect answer. Was easier than I thought :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [lang function](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-lang):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:td1="urn:schemas-TOURDATA:SchemaExtension" 
    xmlns:td2="urn:schemas-TOURDATA:Tour"
    xmlns:td3="urn:TOURDATA:i18n">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/td1:Touren">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="td1:Tour" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="td1:Tour">
        <p><xsl:value-of select="td2:OBJECT_TEXT_NAME/td3:string[lang('de-DE')]"/></p>
        <p><xsl:value-of select="td2:OBJECT_TEXT_NAME/td3:string[lang('en-GB')]"/></p>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This has the advantage over [explicitly comparing the `xml:lang` attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16703876/2032514) that the `xml:lang` attributes can be specified in ancestor elements only.